# Serializing object to dictionary with json,net

Tags: c#, json.net

Can json.net serialize class objects into a simple dictionary?

```
public class CommitData
{
    public AddressDTO Property { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Appointment { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Closed { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public string LenderRef { get; set; }

    public string YearBuilt { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Custom { get; set; }
 }

public class AddressDTO
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

**When serializing I want to get:**

`{

  "Property.Address1": "",

  "Property.Address2": "uyg",

  "LenderRef": "yguyg",

  "Closed": date_here
}`

And similarly deserialize a json string like above into the CommitData object?

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333820/how-to-flatten-a-referenced-object-into-two-json-net-properties-on-the-referer? In general it seems that it cannot be done with JSON.NET. Anyway, JSON.NET will serialize your address into its own object so when deserializing you will get a `CommitData` object with an `AddressDTO` property that you can access with the `.` as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is a bit of work. You have full control of how your object is serialized and deserialized by implementing your own `JsonConverter`. With that, you can flatten it and unflatten it by doing simple string manipulation. A proper generic solution could be acomplished but would take a lot more work as you would need to consider multiple levels of recursion on each property but if you only care about this case in particular then use [Custom JsonConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

Here is an example of a converter Json.net uses internally:

[KeyValuePairConverter.cs](https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/KeyValuePairConverter.cs)

Hope it helps.