# Is it possible to skip object name during Json Serialization?

Tags: c#, json.net, json-serialization

I have the below properties of an object:

```
public string SenderAccount { get; set; }
public string ReceiverAccount { get; set; }
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
public string Currency { get; set; }
public Info Info { get; set; }
```

And I want to have an output like this:

```
{ "sender_account":"1753154", 
  "receiver_account":"1753242",
  "amount":15,
  "currency":"USD",
  "test":1, 
  "key":"_MERCHANT_KEY_",
  "ts":_TIMESTAMP_, 
  "sign":"_SIGN_" 
}
```

Where **test,key,ts and sign**, belong to Info object.
Now I want to skip this part:

```
1."Info":
2.{
3.     "test":0,
4.     "key":"mkey",
5.     "ts":time_stamp,
6.     "sign":"signature"
7.}
```

But to output only `Info` variables. 
Reason is that from api documentation provided they use all time those Info variables to request.

*Edit:* I need to skip rows 1,2,7 during serialization.

Comment: Complementing the comment by @Ive, you will also need to create properties in your base class to return Info's Test, Key and Ts properties

Comment: o.O ok, Ive deleted the comment... Anyways, he said "use [JsonIgnore] attribute" (in your Info property)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json.NET serialize property on the same level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658955/json-net-serialize-property-on-the-same-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
Object1 object1 = new Object1
{
    sender_account = "1753154",
    receiver_account = "1753242",
    amount = 15,
    currency = "USD",
    Info = new Info
    {
        test = 1,
        key = "_MERCHANT_KEY_",
        ts = "_TIMESTAMP_",
        sign = "_SIGN_"
    }
};
```

And serialize it like:

```
var resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    object1.sender_account,
    object1.receiver_account,
    object1.amount,
    object1.currency,
    object1.Info.test,
    object1.Info.key,
    object1.Info.ts,
    object1.Info.sign,
});
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "sender_account": "1753154",
    "receiver_account": "1753242",
    "amount": 15,
    "currency": "USD",
    "test": 1,
    "key": "_MERCHANT_KEY_",
    "ts": "_TIMESTAMP_",
    "sign": "_SIGN_"
}
```

Comment: The point is that i want to keep in same object (object1 to have an instance of object2 and during serialization to skip *Object2 {...}* ), as *Info* will be used everywhere, in all API requests.

Edit: Object2 name, so in output will be only its variables

Comment: @Tecno Will it be possible to update your question and show exactly how you want the JSON to look like?

Comment: @Tecno see my updated answer and let me know if it is useful?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i think this is what i need: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658955/json-net-serialize-property-on-the-same-level