# How do I serialize (JSON) an object/class but not its children

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have:

```
public Class City
{
    public long ID { get; set }
    ...
    public State State { get; set; }
    ...
}
public Class State
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public Country { get; set; }
    ...
}
public Class Country 
{
   public long ID {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

in my code I serialize a list`<Country>` and list`<State>`, etc...
The problem is if I serialize my list of Cities  I get something like this:

```
{
  "ID": 3119841,
  "Name": "A Coruna",
  ...
  "State": {
    "ID": 3336902,
    "Name": "Galicia",
    "Country": {
      "ID": 2510769,
      "Name": "Spain",
      ...
      }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

this cause memory and performance issues when deserializing due to having thousands of copies of the same country object and state object, etc... what I would like to generate is:

```
{
  "ID": 3119841,
  "Name": "A Coruna",
  ...
  "StateID": 3336902,
  ...
}
```

and then I will link up the city to the states (which I will have linked up to the country, etc.)
If I use the Ignore flag (JsonIgnoreAttribute) on the fields in the state and country classes, then I will not be able to Serialize them (I think)...

How do I achieve what I am after? (I am currently using Json.NET, but am happy to use anything that will accomplish the goal.)

Comment: What is `StateID`? Is it a property from the `State` object? Could you literally what you want to do?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use PreserveReferencesHandling (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) instead of not serializing at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude a child structure from being serialized, you can use the [`[JsonIgnore]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) attribute:

```
public class City
{
    public long ID { get; set }
    ...
    [JsonIgnore]
    public State State { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

If you want to flatten the structure, things become more complex. Your options are:

1. Create an intermediate flattened structure, as the result of e.g. a Linq projection.
2. Create a custom contract resolver for your structure, an example that may provide some inspiration on how to achieve this can be found in this question: [How to flatten a referenced object into two json.net properties on the referer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333820/how-to-flatten-a-referenced-object-into-two-json-net-properties-on-the-referer)
3. Expose the additional properties of your `State` class that you want to "flatten" in the `City` class as properties:

```
    public long StateID { get { return State.ID; } }
```

Note that some frameworks will also require you to add the `[ScriptIgnore]` and/or `[NonSerialized]` attributes, in addition to or as alternatives of the `[JsonIgnore]`.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to ignore those properties, he wants to flatten the list.

Comment: So then also add a property for it: `public long StateId { get { return State.Id; } /* Optional set */ set { State = new State(value); } }`, also, should add `NonSerialized` and `ScriptIgnore` as attributes as well on that `State` property.

Answer (score 2):

You add [[NonSerialized]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on top of that field.

To have a plain object (no childs), you can create a model for that object and map the required properties.

```
public class City
{
    public long ID { get; set }
    ...
    [NonSerialized()]
    public State State { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

To have a plain object (no childs), you can **create a model** for that object and **map required properties** (only the properties you need).

```
public class CityModel
{
    public long ID { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public long StateID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now we map the **required properties.** (this can be in a function that you can use when you want)

```
var cityModel = new CityModel {
    ID = city.ID,
    Name = city.Name,
    ...
    StateID = city.State.ID
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @EBrown I appreciate your attention, now is answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the State property using `JsonIgnore` and have an additional property called StateID which gets its value from the State object.

```
public Class City
{
    public long ID { get; set }
    ...
    public int StateID 
    {
         get
         {
             return State.ID;
         }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public State State { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your most appropriate solution is follows; first, add all the required attributes to refuse serialization on your `State` object (which set you use totally depends on what serailizer you use):

`JsonIgnore`: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm

`ScriptIgnore`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

`NonSerialized` (fields only): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

After doing so, I recommend you add a property that can manipulate the state object by ID:

```
public class City
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    ...
    [JsonIgnore, ScriptIgnore]
    public State State { get; set; }
    public long StateID
    {
        get { return State.ID; }
        /* Optionally include a set; some JSON serializers may complain in
        absence of it, up to you to experiment with */
        set { State = new State(value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

This completely preserves your structure, and a well-designed constructor in `State` can handle accepting an `Id` and building a `State` object from it. If you can't build a `State` object from `Id` alone, and your JSON Serializer requires a `set` mutator on it, then you could simply empty the body of it.

You can expand this to your other objects as well:

```
public class State
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    ...
    [JsonIgnore, ScriptIgnore]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public long CountryId
    {
        get { return Country.Id; }
        set { Country = new Country(value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

The major advantage to this model, is that if you do it correctly and design `State` and `Country` appropriately, your JSON Serializer will do **all** the heavy lifting.

Also, as Alex mentioned, you may also create Contract Resolvers, though this is extra work.

Comment: Throwing an error on [NonSerialized]. I don't believe you can use that flag on custom class object.  Works perfect on a string, int, etc, but blows up on Country, State, etc.

Comment: @Rogala My mistake, it's only allowed on `Field`s. (`Attribute 'NonSerialized' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations.`)

Answer (score 0):

This all really depends on your data set. When dealing with a large dataset, I simply use the [JsonIgnore] flag on the property. From there, I would request the cities and states async.  I would put the states in a IEnumerable, and then use a LINQ query to populate the IEnumerable of cities.

Something like this:

```
Cities.ToList().ForEach((c) =>
                    {
                        c.State= States.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == c.StateId);
                    });
```

Also, I tend to use virtual properties to reference other objects like State.

Something like this:

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey("StateId")]
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a localdb at my disposal, then I would use a different solution.

If it's a small enough dataset, I just serialize the whole object and let JSon.Net do the heavy lifting.

I'm pretty sure you cannot use [NonSerialized] with a custom class property. At least, it threw an error on my-side.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ScriptIgnore]:

```
public Class City
{
    public long ID { get; set }
    ...

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public State State { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @EBrown [this like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.applytooverrides%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)